# Need a way to monitor device data usage for 5 devices

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, developer-program, billing

We are a small business and provide Iphones to some of our employees with the understanding that the business will pay for all the data consumed by specific apps.

Is there a centralized management tool to capture this type of info, or a decentralized application that will transmit this data as needed to another interface?

Our business is only concerned with these metrics and doesn't want to get consumed with a full mdm suite.

Comment: Due to how Apple architected iOS, apps can't know the data being used by the iPhone but not by other apps. An app can measure total data but it won't know where that data came from or went to. Are you interested in total cellular data used (assuming that you don't care about wifi data)?

Comment: You could run it through a forced VPN, and track all usage. MDM is likely the best way to go about it though. Or just configure the VPN by user, and have it run 24/7.